# How to turn multiple t.test results into a publishable table?

Tags: r, format, kable, broom, t.test

I have these lines of code to perform a t-test in R:

```
t_test_1 <- t.test(w$bks, b$bks, var.equal = TRUE, conf.level = 0.95)

t_test_2 <- t.test(w$t, b$t, var.equal = TRUE, conf.level = 0.95)
```

Once I have the t-test results I would like to include all the results in one single table and have the standard errors show underneath each estimate.

I´ve tried using gt, broom, rempsyc, gt and kable but I cant seem to be able to get the std error in parenthesis to display underneath the estimates in an understandable table.